# How to physically move the Prefix.pch and Info.plist files

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I've reorganized almost all the files of my project in the physical directory structure so that they are all in one physical directory.  But, I can't seem to move the **Prefix.pch** or **Info.Plist** files without problems.

My method of moving the other files was to

(1) delete their references in **Xcode**,

(2) physically move them with Finder to their new physical directory and

(3) in **Xcode** to add them back into the project.

Are there settings somewhere in my project that have specific knowledge of the physical locations of these two files that I have to update as well?

Comment: are you having trouble because of a source code repository?

Answer (score 4):

There are build settings called **`Prefix header`** and **`Info.plist File`**. You have to change the path to the new path for these settings also.

And to add on, you don't have to delete the reference and add again. After moving the file , you can click on the Xcode reference of the file. Then in the file inspector there is a small rectangle box near the 'location' setting. If you click on this you can specify where the file actually exists.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I want to do the same with you. You can do it like what you want. But after that you need to change the "Build Setting" for the pch and plist file.

[image]
[image]